# Program gets aborted before new throws bad_alloc

Tags: c++, operating-system

below is a small C++-program that apparently gets aborted in a number of cases before "new" throws an exception:

```
int main(){
   try{
      while(true)
         new char[2];
   }
   catch(...){
      while(true);
   }
}
```

The program was first compiled with MinGW/g++ 4.6.1 and then executed on a 32-bit Windows 7 system via the shell. No serious other programs (in terms of memory/CPU consumption) were running at the time. The program terminated before entering the catch-block. When compiling and running the program under Linux (Debian 7.3, gcc/c++ 4.7.2, 24GB memory) the program behaved similarly. (The reason for the infinite loop in the catch-block is to avoid anything there that might throw exceptions - particularly I/O.)
Something surprising (to me at least) happened when launching the program twice on the Windows system: If the program was launched in two different shells (almost) simultaneously, then neither of the two processes terminated before a new-exception was thrown.
Also unexpected to me was the observation that only a moderate enlargement of the size of the allocated chunks of memory (by replacing "2" in the fourth line with "9") made the premature termination disappear on the Windows system. On the Linux machine a much more drastic enlargement was needed to avoid the termination: approx. 40,000,000 bytes per block were necessary to prevent termination.

What am I missing here? Is this normal/intended behavior of the involved operating systems? And if so, doesn't this undermine the usefulness of exceptions - at least in the case of dynamic allocation failure? Can the OS settings be modified somehow (by the user) to prevent such premature terminations? And finally, regarding "serious" applications: At what point (w.r. to dynamic memory allocation) do I have to fear my application getting abruptly aborted by the OS?

Comment: Are you sure the program is being aborted and not just ending?  It's possible the `while(true);` loop in the catch block is optimized out by the compiler.  If that's the case, you catch the error and then the program ends.

Comment: So the compiler can optimise "freeze" to mean "go on, exit." ? I can understand the compiler can optimise so it doesn't actually eat any CPU but actually exiting would change behaviour properly

Comment: @Coda17: I replaced the infinite loop in the catch-block by unsigned u = 3; while( u > 0 ) u = u*u; which never never stops - with the same result concerning termination on Win 7

Comment: @Teilhart: The compiler can trivially detect that you never do anything with `u`, so it removes it from the program.  Then there's an empty loop, so it removes that from the program.  (This is due to a special rule in C++ that says compilers may assume that loops are not infinite)

Comment: @Mooing Duck: Would adding a line such as std::cout << u; right after the infinite while-loop prevent the compiler from optimizing it away?

Comment: @Teilhart: Nope, because there's nothing in the loop.  Make a global variable, and `++` that in the loop.  And then after the loop put a `cout << global;`. Then the loop "has effects" which can't be optimized out.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: I meant putting std::cout << u; after the non-empty loop u = 3; while( u > 0 ) u = u*u; exponentiating u. Do you think this would also work - even though u is local to the catch-block and not global?

Comment: @Teilhart: Yeah, I mixed two ideas on accident.  If you have the `cout << u`, it doesn't need to be global.  (Although be sure the variable is `unsigned`.  `signed` don't play well with infinite loops)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this normal/intended behavior of the involved operating systems?

Yes, it's known as "overcommit" or "lazy allocation". Linux (and I think Windows, but I never program for that OS) will allocate virtual memory to the process when you request it, but won't try to allocate physical memory until you access it. That's the point where, if there is no available RAM or swap space, the program will fail. Or, in the case of Linux at least, other processes might be randomly killed so you can loot their memory.

Note that, when doing small allocations like this, the process will allocate larger lumps and place them in a heap; so the allocated memory will typically be accessed immediately. A large allocation will be allocated directly from the OS and so your test program won't access that memory - which is why you observed that the program didn't abort when you allocated large blocks.

> And if so, doesn't this undermine the usefulness of exceptions - at least in the case of dynamic allocation failure?

Yes, it does rather.

> Can the OS settings be modified somehow (by the user) to prevent such premature terminations?

On Linux, there's a system variable to control the overcommit policy:

```
echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

The value 2 means to never overcommit - allocations will fail if they ask for more than the currently uncommitted RAM plus swap. 1 means to never fail an allocation. 0 (the default) means to guess whether an allocation request is reasonable.

I've no idea whether Windows is similarly configurable.

Comment: Here's how the Win32 API works, though I don't know which params C++ passes.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx  I _think_ C++ passes `MEM_COMMIT` in C++ for the reasons mentioned in this question.